# How to enable dropdown after clicking certain options from the first dropdown in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have tables namely `educations` and `school_courses` from my database. I have two separate dropdowns for the said tables. In the `educations` there is a column named `has_course` which has 2 values, either 1 or 0, if the value is 1, then it has course, 0 if none. I just want to enable the dropdown for school_courses if the selected value from the educations dropdown has 1 as its value in `has_course` column. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-if or ng-show to hide the second dropdown

```
<select ng-model="education" ng-options="option.name for option in data.educations track by option.id">
</select>

<select ng-if="education === 1" ng-model="course" ng-options="option.name for option in data.courses track by option.id">          
</select>
```